# Sort an activerecord result set by another array of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

How do I order this activerecord result set based on a another array of ids?

I perform an initial query on my activerecord model:

```
results = Foo.first(5)
results.each do |r| 
  #do some stuff initially with these records. 
  #5 records returned with ids: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
end
```

I then do some further processing which results in another array of ids:

```
desired_order_ids = [3,1,4,5,2]
```

I want to order `results` by `Foo.id` in the order specified by the `desired_order_ids` array of ids. How to do this? In reality the above query will retrieve 1000 records, so I am looking for the most memory efficient way to do this?

Comment: The most efficient way is to sort in the database, but you need to provide more information about the tables on how you are sorting the data to get any meaningful answers.

Comment: I agree with you but I didn't want to write an essay to explain the backstory coming to the conclusion that doing a db sort is not an option. In a nutshell, I'm querying retrieving a result set then performing some statistical regression analysis on that result set that will apply specifically to that result set and cannot be known ahead of time (and cannot therefore be stored in the db). Maybe there is a way I can store in db but I'd say this is first pass get it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need the end result to be an `ActiveRecord::Relation`? If you're fine with converting to an `Array`, this should be the simplest solution:

```
desired_order_ids.map { |id| results[id - 1] }
```

Another option could be:

```
results.sort_by { |result| desired_order_ids.index(result.id) }
```

Comment: I went with this answer as I was able to make use of the existing result set in memory without having to go back and hit the db again. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the DBMS you are using, but I think this will work on most databases:

```
Foo.all.order('id=3 desc, id=1 desc, id=4 desc, id=5 desc, id=2 desc')
```

You can use a method to build the argument passed to `order` like this:

```
def order_string(field_name, arr)
  arr.map { |val| "#{field_name}=#{val} desc" }.join(', ')
end
```

and call it like:

```
Foo.all.order(order_string('id', [3, 1, 4, 5, 2]))
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed!